# jquery working but syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function()
{
$(".error").hide();
$("#submit").click(function()
{
    //form validate
    var name= $("input#fullname").val();
        if (name == "")
        {
            $("label#name_error").show();
            $("input#fullname").focus();
            return false;
        }
    var email= $("input#email").val();
        if (email == "")
        {
            $("label#email_error").show();
            $("input#email").focus();
            return false;
        }
    var subject= $("input#subject").val();
        if (subject == "")
        {
            $("label#subject_error").show();
            $("input#subject").focus();
            return false;
        }
    var textarea= $("textarea#textarea").val();
        if (textarea == "")
        {
            $("label#textarea_error").show();
            $("textarea#textarea").focus();
            return false;
        }

    var dataString = 'fullname='+name+'&email='+email+'&subject='+subject+'&textarea='+textarea;
    //alert (dataString);return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function()
        {
            $("#form").html("<div id='message'></div>");
            $("#message").html("<h2 id='success'>Query Submitted!</h2>").append("<p>You will be contacted shortly...</p><p>Reload the page to submit another query.</p>").hide().fadeIn(1500)
        }
    })
    return false;
});
});
```

its just a small question

I have this website which has been working perfectly for the past 2-3 months ... but today when I accidentally wandered into the resource section of chrome's console window there was an error saying

> > "uncaught reference error: $ is not defined"

I haven't found a satisfactory answer on the web anywhere ... your thoughts?

here is the head section... i have not included any scripts anywhere else on the page

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cq.css" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="form.js"></script>

    <!--share-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "ur-c6d56dfc-f929-5bbf-a456-178fc403ae45"});</script>

    <!--share ends here-->



</head>
```

Comment: Do you successfully import jQuery ? I'm not sure *"has been working perfectly"* means the same for you and me...

Comment: It seems you are missing the jQuery plugin at top of this script.

Comment: Is the page working now? Can you share the script inclusion portion of your page?

Comment: yes jquery is ther in my folder ... i have linked it ... i get the email delivered from yhe form through ajax .. everything is working ... but the console window shows otherwise

Comment: It sounds like jQuery hasn't been included by the time this function is called.  Right click your webpage when viewing it and view source.  Verify jQuery is being included.  I have had this problem on ASP.NET projects.  I had to include jQuery at the top of the page and include any scripts at the end of the form, because of how the page gets built.

Comment: i mean ... there is no error what-so-ever ... this does not hinder with usability ... but this is just like a thing which will remain in the back of my head ... as to why this happened

Comment: See you have `form.js` above jquery and after jquery. You can use only one of them.

Comment: FYI, SyntaxError !== ReferenceError. Also, you may want to learn about DRY code. You code has a lot of unnecessary repetition.

Comment: could you elaborate please ?

Comment: DRY means *"don't repeat yourself"*. The code for getting each input is nearly identical, and can be reduced dramatically by extracting the similar parts, and injecting the parts that differ. I'll do a quick jsFiddle example for you in a minute.

Comment: There are several ways to do it, but here's one: http://jsfiddle.net/vAhEV/1/ Also you may want to check out jQuery's `.serialize()` method, which will build the string for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling your script *before* referencing jQuery. Change your HTML to:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
```

You're also importing the same JavaScript file (form.js) twice.

Comment: Yep, I was about to post the same answer. The fact it is imported twice explains both the error in console and why the application is working correctly.

Comment: thank you ... :) .. JAI, JAMIE and .. i guess .. LOSTDREAMER :)